# Регулярные выражения: оберзать текст, по определенному количеству символов, с тегами не трогая теги

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Задача:
Есть краткое описание с bbcode.
Надо: обрезать  описание по определенному количеству символов не трогая bbcode теги

Например: обрезать описание до 4 символов (при этом не трогая теги)

**Текст:** **0**[img]http://site[/img]**12**[img]http://site[/img]**3**456789

**Должен быть результат:** **0**[img]http://site[/img]**12**[img]http://site[/img]**3**

**Т.е. 0123 вместе с тегами**

Помогите составить паттерн для  preg_match_all()

Попытался таким способом

$text="0[img]http://site[/img]12[img]http://site[/img]3456789";
$pattern = ('/((.?\S{0,4})(?=([img].?[/img])))/isu'); 
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $out);

Не получилось

Answer (score 1):

Одним регулярным выражением тут, вероятно, не обойтись. Предлагаю воспользоваться функцией:

```
function short($str, $length) 
{
    $sourceStr = $str;
    $resultStr = '';
    $posReal = 0; // позиция курсора в исходной строке
    $posSpec = 0; // позиция курсора в строке без учета bb-кода

    while ($posSpec < $length && $posReal < strlen($sourceStr)) {
        // убираем из начальной строки уже обработанные символы
        $str = substr($sourceStr, $posReal);

        $char = substr($str, 0, 1);
        if ($char == '[') {
            // встретили начало bb-кода, добавляем этот код к строке-результату
            if (preg_match('/^\[[^\]]+\][^\[]*\[\/[^\]]+\]/', $str, $match)) {
                $posReal += strlen($match[0]);
                $resultStr .= $match[0];
                continue;
            }
        }

        $resultStr .= $char;
        $posSpec++;
        $posReal++;
    }

    return $resultStr;
}
```